# How do I reference a cordova-plugin from npm / github within my PhoneGap config.xml

Tags: cordova, plugins, phonegap

My current pipeline sees me creating apps that I prepare for the app stores using PhoneGap build. 
I occasionally need to use a plug-in.

For example, I found this plug-in: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-streaming-media which should allow me to create streaming media.

My config.xml file contains entries like this:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
```

Can I assume that this:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-streaming-media" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
```

should therefore also work?

My first attempt using the above config.xml entry resulting in error:

[image]

I appreciate this is a little vague (and horribly naive) but if it's relevant to anyone's own experience I'd welcome the help.

On my list is installing the Cordova pipeline to work with but just now I'm stuck with PhoneGap Build.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your config.xml and run

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-streaming-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
```

Comment: Well that seems to work. Thank you. I see the only difference between your string and mine was the spec which is declared under version on the npm page.